# Можно ли сказать "едет, кружа колесами", "едет кружа колеса"?

Tags: деепричастия

Можно ли сказать "едет, кружа колесами", "едет кружа колеса"? Или используется только "вращая"?

Answer (score 1):

Вращая, крутя. Такие варианты попадались.
Технически "кружа" синонимично обоим вариантам. Но это слово закрепилось за горизонтальным кружением. То есть это будет резать глаз читателю, а в его голове неизбежно будет образ того, как колёса, подобно карусели, вращаются вокруг транспорта.
И думаю, даже смогу объяснить причину такой проблемы. "Кружа" этимологически отсылает нас к кругу, окружности. Это бесконечное равноудалённое от центра количество точек. То есть это в первую очередь не "крутящийся" и не "вращающийся" объект, а объект, описывающий круглую траекторию вокруг (извините за тавтологию) точки, некую орбиту. Когда мы говорим "кружа", то тут же ссылаемся именно к такому, орбитальному движению.
В рамках некого филологического изыска, намерения показать "дыры" в смыслах отдельных слов, можно, конечно, удивить читателя словом "кружа". Вряд ли в словарях найдётся категорическое на сей счёт возражение. Но вряд ли вы, задавая вопрос о том, можно ли так сказать, ставите перед собой цель проводить вот такие жонглирования словами. Посему ответ очевиден: лучше так не говорить.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли сказать "едет, кружа колесами", "едет, кружа колеса"?

Я бы поостерегся такое употреблять. Тут дело не в деепричастии, а в производящем глаголе "кружить", он имеет семантические особенности в употреблении.

Но вообще-то это все надо смотреть в контексте. Тут два момента. Во первых, не знаю, можно ли отнести слово к строго разговорному жанру, но оно точно не подходит для технического и делового стиля. И во-вторых, само значение, семантика слова не очень-то стыкуется с колесами. Не столь важно даже, с горизонтальной осью или вертикальной осью... Вот мельничное колесо (у малых ветряков бывает вполне себе горизонтально) - но разве ж оно **кружит**? Оно в лучшем случае **кружится**.
Кружить - это что-то хаотичное, или поступательное, или под действием какой-то совсем уж внешней силы...

В общем, я думаю, что для художественного, особенно - поэтического, текста ваш вариант вполне пригоден. Но не более, в другом контексте употреблять не стоит.